# Finding the cardinality of a set given a set property.

Tags: combinatorics

**Suppose a set $B$ has the property that $|{X:X \in P(B), |X| = 6}| = 28$. Find $|B|$**

My solution to this problem is as follows:

We know we have $28$ subsets of $B$ with $6$ elements each, so we can write $\frac{n!}{(n-6)!6!} = 28$.

We notice that $28=4*7$. We move $6!$ to the other side so now we have $(2*3*4*5*6)*(4*7) = \frac{n!}{(n-6)!}$. This means that $3*4*5*6*7*8 = n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)$. It follows that $n = 8$, so $|B| = 8$.

**Question:** Is this solution correct and a good way to go about this problem? Is there another way to think about this problem?

Mention: This problem comes from [The Book of Proof](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/) (Section 3.3 problem 4)

Comment: I think it's a brilliant solution! I can't think of a better way to think of it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach is methodical and well reasoned.   It is exactly what you needed to do.

Further, if $\lvert B\rvert = 8$, then the count for subsets of size six is $\dfrac{8!}{2!~6!}$ or $28$, as required.

So your solution checks out okay, too.

---

PS: There is one other numerical solution, but it is $n=-7$ so fails a reality check.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have correctly identified the equation $n!/6!(n-6)!=28$ is the equation to solve. Your approach seems quite efficient (I'm assuming that you realize that you must assume that $n\ge 0$ in the last step).

Another approach would be to note that the equation requires $n\ge 6$ and note that $n!/6!(n-6)!$ is increasing with $n$ and then test with different $n$s. Once you reach $n=8$ you find a match and know that you can stop there as higher values of $n$ will result in larger LHS.